# Removing ListItemButtons from kivy adapter widget

Tags: android, python, listview, kivy

Okay, I am populating a list with listitembuttons based on cities that are searched. It will populate the list with a listitembutton for each city that matches the entered text. When I enter in a new city I want to remove the other listitembuttons and replace them with the new list of cities that I searched for. I am able to remove them using this piece of code.

```
def clear_locations(self):
        for x in self.search_results.adapter.data:
            self.search_results.adapter.data.remove(x)
```

If I use this function to print x i n self.search_results.adapter.data: for example when I searched London: it will print out four cities each in its own ListItemButton. However, it only removes the amount ListItemButtons equal to the amount of new ones created.

Say I search for london first and get four listitembuttons. Then I search for paris. It removes two of the london listitembuttons and adds two paris ones. If i search for murfreesboro, it would remove one of the london listitembuttons and add one murfreesboro one. What I don't get is that the four loop will go through and print all the cities in the data but will only remove the amount equal to the amount of new cities. Any help would be great.

here is the rest of my code: 
main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import json
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):

    location_form = ObjectProperty()
    current_weather = ObjectProperty()

    def show_current_weather(self, location=None):
        self.clear_widgets()

        if location is not None:
            self.current_weather = CurrentWeather(location=location)

        if self.current_weather is None:
            self.current_weather = CurrentWeather()

        if location is None:
            self.current_weather.location = location

        self.current_weather.update_weather()    
        self.add_widget(self.current_weather)

    def add_location(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.location_form)

class CurrentWeather(BoxLayout):
    location = ListProperty(["NewYork", "US"])
    conditions = StringProperty()
    temp = NumericProperty()
    temp_min = NumericProperty()
    temp_max = NumericProperty()
    wind = NumericProperty()
    humidity = NumericProperty()

    def update_weather(self):
        weather_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={},{}&units=imperial&APID=a1bf58ef2e81e600af117e12e13e0ff1"
        weather_url = weather_template.format(*self.location)
        request = UrlRequest(weather_url, self.weather_retrieved)

    def weather_retrieved(self, request, data):
        self.conditions = data['weather'][0]['description']
        self.temp = data['main']['temp']
        self.temp_min = data['main']['temp_min']
        self.temp_max = data['main']['temp_max']
        self.wind = data['wind']['speed']
        self.humidity = data['main']['humidity']

class LocationButton(ListItemButton):
    location = ListProperty()

class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):

    search_input = ObjectProperty() 
    search_results = ObjectProperty()

    def args_converter(self, index, data_item):
        (city, country) = data_item
        return {'location':(city,country)} 

    def web_error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_results.data = ["Either the openweather.org is down", "or you are not connected to the interweb"]

    def clear_locations(self):
        for x in self.search_results.adapter.data:
            self.search_results.adapter.data.remove(x)


    def search_location(self):
        self.clear_locations()      
        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={}&type=like&APID=a1bf58ef2e81e600af117e12e13e0ff1"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location, on_error=self.web_error)


    def found_location(self, request, data):
        try:
            cities = [(d['name'], d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]
        except:
            cities = ["No",  "Citys Found"]
        self.search_results.adapter.data[:]
        self.search_results.adapter.data.extend(cities)
        self.search_results._trigger_reset_populate()



class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

weather.kv

```
#: import main main
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

WeatherRoot:


<WeatherRoot>:
    location_form: add_location_form
    AddLocationForm:
        id: add_location_form

<LocationButton>:
    text: "{}({})".format(self.location[0], self.location[1])
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "40dp"
    color: [1, 1, 1, 1]
    deselected_color: 0,.8,.5,1
    on_press: app.root.show_current_weather(self.location)

<CurrentWeather>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: "{}({})".format(root.location[0], root.location[1])
    Label:
        text: root.conditions
    Label:
        text: "Current Temp: {}".format(root.temp)
    Label:
        text: "Low: {}".format(root.temp_min)
    Label:
        text: "High: {}".format(root.temp_max)
    Label:
        text: "Wind Speed: {}".format(root.wind)
    Label:
        text: "Humiditity: {}".format(root.humidity)
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        Button:
            text: "Add Location"
            on_press: app.root.add_location()
        Button:
            text: "Forcast"

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    search_input: search_box
    search_results: search_results_list
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: 50
            on_text_validate: root.search_location()
        Button:
            text: 'Search'
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.search_location()
        Button:
            text: 'Current Location'
            size_hint_x: 25

    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data = [], cls = main.LocationButton, args_converter = root.args_converter)
```

So if I use the for loop to print x in self.search_results.adapter.data while searching for paris after searching london I get this in the console:

```
(u'London', u'CA')
(u'London', u'GB')
(u'London Borough of Harrow', u'GB')
(u'Londonderry County Borough', u'GB')
```

But if I use remove(x) for x in self.search_results.adapter.data: then I get this while searching for paris after searching for london:
[image]

Comment: Obviously you are working with the book by Dusty Phillips like me, too :-). If you are interested how to remove a SELECTED ListItemButton, take a look at my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981827/python-kivy-listview-how-to-delete-selected-listitembutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE! Found a great solution!

If anyone else has this problem I solved it with

```
def clear_locations(self):
    del self.search_results.adapter.data[:]
```